# How to get Symfony 2 with doctrine ORM to persist related entity only once

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

I have a 'person' entity that has a manyToOne relationship with a 'city' entity:

Here's the person's relationship mapping:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="City", inversedBy="persons", cascade={"persist"})
*/
private $city;
```

and city's:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Person", mappedBy="city")
*/
private $persons;
```

I use the basic Symfony 2 'person' controller generated by doctrine:generate:crud:

```
$entity  = new Person();
$form = $this->createForm(new PersonType(), $entity);
$form->bind($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
}
```

The PersonType form type instantiates a CityType

```
class PersonType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
        $builder
        ->add('city', new CityType())
        ->add('firstname')
        ->add('lastname')
        ->add('gender')
        ...
```

The CityType form type has a single text field

```
class CityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('cityname', 'text');
     }
}
```

When I submit the form, the Person entity is created, as well as the City entity, thanks to the cascade={"persist"}.

The problem arrises when I fill out the form with a city name that already exists in the DB, Doctrine creates another entry with the same city name.

Is there a simple way Doctrine could detect that, and use the existing city_id in the Person table?

Comment: Try to use DataTransformer. Check http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html I'm not sure whether this is the correct solution. I'll try it later and will give you feedback

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It's an interesting option, and I'm currently looking into it. Even though it's not reflected in my question above, the City object has a couple of extra fields that define its uniqueness: state, country. I wonder how that would play out in a data transformer context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @vadim said, you must use datatransformer. It might be confusing at start but after ~30 minutes you will learn it. Keep in mind that around the world, you will have many cities with same name.

The best solution is this; in that text field, user would type a name like `Belgrade, Montana, Usa` (btw; Belgrade is capital of Serbia, just giving you an example of cities with same name). Datatransformer will read DB and find the correct city of Belgrade that you could link with.

After you do this (and it is very simple), that you could build auto-completion for that field. @artworkad suggestion is overly complicated and will bring more problems later.

Comment: Data transformer is the way to go, and I ended up using that option. Powerful stuff. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is, don't cascade persisting of entities. I.e.

```
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $city = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:City')
                   ->findOneByCityname($data['cityname']);

        if($city == null){
            $city = new City();
            $city->setName($data['cityname']);
            $em->persist($city);
            $em->flush();
        }

        $entity->setCity($city);
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is likely to be the best answer to my problem. I find it surprising that the cascading system doesn't allow to specify a couple of unique fields to be used in an 'entity exists' type of scenario. Maybe I should suggest it to the Symfony folks.